# Amazon EFS within diferent zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

Is it possible to use an EFS in AWS for several instances located in different regions?

If not, is it possible to do somethink like that using AWS console?? Doesn't matter latency or throughput between EC2 instance and network volume.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I’m trying to have 2 instances in different zones that share a volume, is it possible with Amazon?

Comment: This answer might help, in conjunction with VPC Peering https://serverfault.com/questions/799016/elastic-file-system-efs-mount-outside-of-aws

Comment: The answer @DusanBajic was kind enough to provide a link to represents the only solution (workaround) available at the moment -- a TCP proxy server on EC2 within the same region as EFS, which you would then use as the mount target from the remote instances, using VPC peering.  This is not an officially-supported solution, but I use it with consistent results between us-west-2 and us-east-1. (I originally developed it for use with an off-site data center without Direct Connect, for an into-AWS migration.) Be mindful of the cost of cross-region data transfer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

EFS can be accessed through Direct Connect or VPN. Estabilsh VPN connection between regions and you can mount EFS with the IP address of the corresponding mount target.